# Save the value of Checked DropDownBoxes after Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select, jquery-events

I found a really nice jQuery plugin from http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#examples.  That transforms a select dropdown box to a checked dropdownbox.  I created seven checked dropdownboxes using the code.  I’m having trouble saving the selection of all seven dropdowns after the page reloads.

The below code creates an alert that splits each selection by a comma dropdown selection.
E.g. D1, D2, D3 are the values selected.

```
alert('Selected values: ' + $('select').multipleSelect('getSelects'));
```

I would like to be able to use this code and save the value to an object that I can use after the page refreshes.  The complication that I am running into is that the line of code only references the latest created dropdown.  Is there someway I can name my dropdowns so that it I can reference the selected values?

I am using this particular example form the Jquery plugin.

```
<head>
    <link href="multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <select multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        ...
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <script src="jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("select").multipleSelect({
            placeholder: "Here is the placeholder"
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm, give an XML ID to each  element you create:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="xxx">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    ...
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

, and use `$("#xxx")` for finding it, instead of `$('select')`